# What are the adjective counterparts for "sense" and "sensibility"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What are the adjective counterparts for "sense" and "sensibility" as in Jane Austen's *Sense and Sensibility*?

Would the one for "sensibility" be "sensible"?

What is the one for "sense"? Does it have the same meaning as "rational"?

Comment: I think OP has the first pairing wrong. The adjectival counterparts of the novel title are *sense:sensible* and *sensibility:[emotionally] sensitive*.

Comment: How does "sensible" mean the opposite of "sensibility"?

Comment: I assumed by "adjective counterpart" you simply meant the adjectival forms corresponding to the two nouns in the book title. Which I understand as a play on words where *sense* refers to rational decision-making, and sensibility refers to the emotions which *may* run counter to that rationalism. That's the only kind of "opposite" I see here.

Comment: @Tim: He didn't say *opposite*, just incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *sensible* is an adjective counterpart to both words.

From Merriam-Webster:

> 3b: emotionally aware and responsive [we are sensible of your problems]
>   4: having, containing, or indicative of good sense or reason : rational, reasonable [sensible people] [made a sensible answer]

So 3b: corresponds to *sensibility* and 4: corresponds to *sense*. Isn't English a wonderful language?

Comment: Yes and no. No because it is confusing.

Comment: Can I add a virtual :-) to my answer?

Comment: I am sensible of the fact that you find this sensible.

Comment: @JeffSahol: Now you confuse me. Peter: As you please. :)

Comment: @Peter: I think you've made pretty much the same distinction I was getting at in my comment to the question. The problem, as evidenced by Jeff's comment above, is that both *sense* and *sensibility* have a range of potential meanings. Lucky for Austen, as it gave her the chance to create a memorable book title wherein we're invited to consider a particular pair of those meanings which can (given the right novel as context) be seen as opposites.

Comment: Her sequel was going to be called "Notable and Noteworthy", IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Meaning may have shifted since the novel was written, but I think you are right about "sense" being "rational". "Sensibility" corresponds to "perceptive" or "sensitive".